# What's the difference between T and def in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I was working with some SQL earlier that got me wondering what the difference was between these two typings.

In my example, I have 2 GroovyRowResults - pastData and currentData. Now, I need to compare 2 points from these result sets. These values should both be of indefinite type. So, when defining them, what's the difference between

```
def pastResult = pastData[commonKey]
def currentResult = currentData[commonKey]

if(pastResult == currentResult){
    doSomething()
}
```

and

```
T pastResult = pastData[commonKey]
T currentResult = currentData[commonKey]

if(pastResult == currentResult){
    doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `T` has been declared in your method/class earlier.  In that case, it's a [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) and the `T` refers to the same type of object consistently, whereas `def` is basically just an alias for `Object`.

T doesn't guarantee the two objects are the exact same class (they may just implement the same interface, or one may be a subclass), it does create more of a contract in the objects that you are dealing with.  If you pass the same types of objects into the method, then there will be no difference, but if you pass different or unexpected types, it is more useful.

In other words, in Groovy it's done for readability and consistency, and using generics is much better than using dynamic typing.

Comment: Thanks Igor! I feel like I've seen you around a bunch in my long time lurking. I know that groovy is a dynamic language - so I don't have to cast something after using def to create it. Does this make the differences between Object and T slightly less significant than def and T?

Comment: @Zyxer22 Yeah no problem.  As for the differences... I don't think there are much as long as you're not changing the type after initializing the object.  `def` mostly comes in handy when you're converting from a list to an array to a linked list, etc. (whereas Object doesn't let you do that).  But for your purposes, I think `def` vs `Object` (and in practice, even `T`) are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the second example will work unless there is some kind of object called T. Check this link
http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_variable_definition

Comment: Groovy uses the java libraries, so it should work, but I tested it out just to be sure.
    import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.BindCaller.T
    public <T> foo(){
        T bar = 5
        T bar2 = 4
        bar == bar2
    }

Comment: Comment formatting did not work and apparently I can't edir. I just imported the bindcaller.T java library and made a public <T> void foo() function that used those values above.